# Is there any way to make Hibernate use literal values rather than bind variables?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, database-partitioning

In Oracle I have a partitioned table.  The partitions are of different sizes and have different data distribution.

I would like to have hibernate issue SQL statements that includes a literal value for the partition key column rather than a bind variable. It should use bind variables for any other values of course.

Using a literal for the partition key will allow Oracle to come up with a plan specific to the known partition and the collected statistics.  This might also be useful for columns that have a histogram in place for skewed data.

It would be preferable to specify this in the entity otherwise we will need to do it in each query.   Is there a way to do this in hibernate?

We are on hibernate 3.6.1 using the Oracle 10g Dialect.

If there is not a way to do it natively in Hibernate, can I create a user type or dialect or something to make this happen?

Comment: Would 11g adaptive cursor sharing solve your problems?

Comment: @jonearles Yes perhaps 11g will solve these problems via adaptive cursor sharing and/or cardinality feedback.  We are working towards getting 11g up to production but there is considerable testing to be done there.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that partition pruning itself works with bind variables, but the query plan within the partition (e.g., join strategy) does not?

Comment: In our multi-tenant setup, tables are partitioned by tenant.  Different tenants have different volumes and disribution of data depending on the features they use and their business.  Oracle makes better decisions when using the partition-level statistics than global table statistics.  Partition pruning happens at runtime either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, literal values are not supported in Hibernate. I doubt if you can make a workaround but I guess you're looking for another solution.

Comment: If there absolutely no way to do it in Hibernate we will not use hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the namedNativeQuery
here is a sample implementation.

Entity class is

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = DBCatalog)
@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name="partitionTR1",query ="SELECT * FROM DATAMARTTRANSACTIONHISTORY PARTITION (tr1) where id=?",resultClass=DataMartTable.class)
public class DataMartTransactionHistory implements TransactionHistory {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private TransactionStatus transactionStatus;
... other props...
}
```

and here is a dao implementation.

```
public DataMartTransactionHistory findDataMartTransactionHistoryTR1(Long id) {
    Query namedQuery = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("partitionTR1");
    namedQuery.setLong(0, id);
    return (DataMartTransactionHistory)namedQuery.list().get(0);
}
```

Comment: by the way my table is as followed.
CREATE TABLE DATAMARTTRANSACTIONHISTORY
(
  ID                       NUMBER(19)           NOT NULL,
....
  TRANSACTIONSTATUS        NUMBER(10)
)
PARTITION BY LIST(TRANSACTIONSTATUS) (partition tr1 values(1), partition tr2 values(2))

Comment: In your named query you have "where id=?".  Are you saying this will be replaced with a literal value rather than a bind variable?

Comment: no it is a bind variable I have added the "PARTITION (tr1)" as literal. you can add more here. if you give me a, your specific usecase, I can generate you a specific example.

Comment: I see, so you have a named query for each partition?

Comment: exactly, does it meet your requirements.

Comment: Kindof.  At the moment it is not necessary to change any java code when a new partition is added.  This does not seem like a better approach than using a native query and string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can set a unique comment at every "interesting" call site, so you can control Oracle's bind variable peeking.

```
...
query = session.createQuery("...");
...
query.setString("param1", "FOO");
query.setInteger("param2", param2Value);
...
query.setComment("param1 = \"FOO\"");
...
```

In this way, the optimizer will see `"FOO"` at hard parse time (as usual). In future invocations, Oracle will search for an exact copy of the SQL to reuse the execution plan. As the comment makes the query effectively unique, this will give you the same execution plan that was calculated with `"FOO"`, and not any other value of `param1`.

You must be careful because the optimizer will also use the value of `param2Value` to calculate the execution plan, so it might interfere. But I think that at least it is worth a try.

Comment: We disabled bind variable peeking because of the plan instability that it introduced.  One example was a nightly batch job - whichever customer's instance ran first set the plan for those that followed.  This was not always good.

Comment: Well that is the whole point of this workaround: queries that should use different plans get textually different SQL, so you don't have to disable peeking and lose its advantages. But well, you are not going to reenable it for this.

Comment: Have you thought about using SQL profiles for the queries that would benefit from the literal?

Comment: The bind variable peeking problem was caused by an old application.  A new one is being written using Hibernate.  I think we will be forced to use hibernate "native queries" where this matters and string-concatenate in the literals.